# How do I write Visual Basic Code to read the input from a barcode scanner?

Tags: vb.net

I want to write software in visual basic that reads the barcode of various items into my program. Any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: How are you going to obtain the barcode? Are you going to use a camera? An already existing image? A webcam? Or possibly even a proper barcode scanner?

In the latter instance a proper barcode scanner will usually work as a keyboard, and send the barcode as a set of keystrokes to the computer.

Comment: ya i have the barcode scanner.. but i dont knw how shld i write the code in vb so that it reads the barcode..

Comment: You are going to have to tell us about your barcode reader then.  Manufacuter, make, model#, interface type, etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a hardware barcode scanner to hand it will almost certainly imitate a keyboard, and send the barcode as keystrokes (no special code required, just a textbox and it will put it in there once it is focused).

If you go to the manufacturers website, you will find exactly what it does, and even special barcodes for programming your scanner (such as sending newlines at the end of barcodes, etc).

Otherwise, see my comment to your question above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need code to read the barcode scanner. It usually comes into the system exactly like it came from the keyboard. Make your app work for the keyboard and you are there.